# value not displaying and having errors in console for Vue.js (laravel6)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

I'm having an error for displaying a data from vue.js
This is the error.

[image: the error]

this is the vue.js result

[image]

I have a data in counter1 and the rest has no value yet.
But I want it to display blank if it has no value yet and display the data that has value already.

Here is my vue.js script:

```
<script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data:{
            queue:{},

        },
        mounted(){
            this.getQueue();
        },
        methods:{
            getQueue(){
                axios.get('api/display/showqueue')
                .then((response)=>{
                    this.queue=response.data
                })

                .catch(function (error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        }

    })
</script>
```

And here is my HTML for vue.js data output:

```
<div id="app" class="row">

                  <div  class="col-sm-6">
                    <div  class="card bg-gradient-lighter mt-3 shadow">
                        <div class="card-header-lg">
                        <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.cashier1.department">@{{ (queue.cashier1 || {}).department}}</h3>
                        <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-else>-</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body-sm">
                        <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold"  v-if="queue.cashier1"><strong>@{{ (queue.cashier1 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.cashier1 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer-sm">
                          <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 1</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div  class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter shadow mt-3">
                        <div class="card-header-lg">
                            <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-if="queue.cashier2.department">@{{ (queue.cashier2 || {}).department}}</h3>
                            <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-else>-</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body-sm">
                            <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold"  v-if="queue.cashier2"><strong>@{{ (queue.cashier2 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.cashier2 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer-sm">
                            <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter shadow mt-3">
                                <div class="card-header-lg">
                                    <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-if="queue.accounting1.department">@{{ (queue.accounting1 || {}).department}}</h3>
                                    <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-else>-</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body-sm">
                                    <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold"  v-if="queue.accounting1"><strong>@{{ (queue.accounting1 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.accounting1 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer-sm">
                                    <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 1</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter mt-3 shadow">
                        <div class="card-header-lg">
                        <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.accounting2.department">@{{ (queue.accounting2 || {}).department}}</h3>
                        <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-else>-</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body-sm">
                            <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold" v-if="queue.accounting2"><strong>@{{ (queue.accounting2 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.accounting2 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer-sm">
                          <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter shadow mt-3">
                            <div class="card-header-lg">
                                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.registrar1.department">@{{ (queue.registrar1 || {}).department}}</h3>
                                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-else>-</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body-sm">
                                <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold" v-if="queue.registrar1"><strong>@{{ (queue.registrar1 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.registrar1 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer-sm">
                                <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter mt-3">
                            <div class="card-header-lg">
                                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.registrar2.department">@{{ (queue.registrar2 || {}).department}}</h3>
                                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-else>-</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body-sm">
                                <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold" v-if="queue.registrar2"><strong>@{{ (queue.registrar2 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.registrar2 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer-sm">
                                <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
```

How can I make it that whenever I have a data available, It will display on the page but if I have no data. It will just leave it blank and have no errors.

Comment: It's beacuse of your v-if you have to properly handle it otherwise remove it .
your v-if should be v-if="queue.cashier1 && queue.cashier1.department"

Comment: hi @saravana. I tried to change the v-if condition but its still not showing.

Comment: are you getting the same error or something different

Comment: You need to handle every if condition's 
v-if="queue.cashier1 && queue.cashier1.department"
v-if="queue.cashier2 && queue.cashier2.department" 
v-if="queue.accounting1 && queue.accounting1.department"
.....
and so on

Comment: the error here is you are trying to access a property from null or undefined value.
suppose you have an object like below obj = {prop1:{color:red}} 

case 1 :: obj.prop1.color // red
case 2 :: obj.prop1.color2 // undefined since prop1 not having color2 property
case 3 :: obj.prop2.color // it will throw an error obj.prop2 will return undefined if you try to access something from undefined , you will get an error.

Comment: Yes I tried changing it all. I have notice that its not the value that its not showing. Its the whole "div on id=app". I tried moving the "id=app" for the cashier counter 1 div only and its working, but when I try to place it on a div that includes all div that has the vue value. Its not showing at all. As if the div with id=app is erased on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this error because you are trying to access property of `undefined` as `queue` is empty initially and `queue.cashier1` and all other properties are not defined. So, try this by adding a check if data is loading and their is no error fetching result.

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="!isLoading && !isError" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter mt-3 shadow">
            <div class="card-header-lg">
                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.cashier1 && queue.cashier1.department">@{{ (queue.cashier1 || {}).department}}</h3>
                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-else>-</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body-sm">
                <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold" v-if="queue.cashier1"><strong>@{{ (queue.cashier1 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.cashier1 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer-sm">
                <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter shadow mt-3">
            <div class="card-header-lg">
                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.cashier2 && queue.cashier2.department">@{{ (queue.cashier2 || {}).department}}</h3>
                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-else>-</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body-sm">
                <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold" v-if="queue.cashier2"><strong>@{{ (queue.cashier2 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.cashier2 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer-sm">
                <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter shadow mt-3">
            <div class="card-header-lg">
                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.accounting1 && queue.accounting1.department">@{{ (queue.accounting1 || {}).department}}</h3>
                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-else>-</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body-sm">
                <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold" v-if="queue.accounting1"><strong>@{{ (queue.accounting1 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.accounting1 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer-sm">
                <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter mt-3 shadow">
            <div class="card-header-lg">
                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.accounting2 && queue.accounting2.department">@{{ (queue.accounting2 || {}).department}}</h3>
                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-else>-</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body-sm">
                <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold" v-if="queue.accounting2"><strong>@{{ (queue.accounting2 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.accounting2 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer-sm">
                <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter shadow mt-3">
            <div class="card-header-lg">
                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.registrar1 && queue.registrar1.department">@{{ (queue.registrar1 || {}).department}}</h3>
                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-else>-</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body-sm">
                <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold" v-if="queue.registrar1"><strong>@{{ (queue.registrar1 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.registrar1 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer-sm">
                <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter mt-3">
            <div class="card-header-lg">
                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.registrar2 && queue.registrar2.department">@{{ (queue.registrar2 || {}).department}}</h3>
                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-else>-</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body-sm">
                <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold" v-if="queue.registrar2"><strong>@{{ (queue.registrar2 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.registrar2 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer-sm">
                <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" v-else>
    <span v-if="isLoading">Loading...</span>
    <span v-else>Error loading data...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data:{
            queue:{},
            isLoading: false,
            isError: false

        },
        mounted(){
            this.getQueue();
        },
        methods:{
            getQueue(){
                this.isLoading = true;
                this.isError = false
                axios.get('api/display/showqueue')
                .then((response)=>{
                    this.queue=response.data
                    this.isLoading = false
                })

                .catch(function (error){
                    console.log(error);
                    this.isLoading = false
                    this.isError = true
                });
            }
        }

    })
</script>
```

Comment: This is working but after the data load.the design of my page destroyed I dont know why.

Comment: @sigel Just try removing class `row` from `#app` and give on `div`s. I have changed my answer please check if it works

Answer (score 2):

This has happened when your mounted function is fired but data not exit. [See Vue life cycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).

What I do to resolve this issue. I take a loading flog. like this.

```
<script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data:{
            queue:{},
            loading: false,

        },
        mounted(){
            this.getQueue();
        },
        methods:{
            getQueue(){
                this.loagind = true;
                axios.get('api/display/showqueue')
                .then((response)=>{
                    this.queue=response.data
                    this.loading = false
                })

                .catch(function (error){
                    console.log(error);
                    this.loading = false
                });
            }
        }

    })
</script>
```

now Html code

```
<div id="app" class="row">

                  <div  class="col-sm-6" v-if="!loading">
                    <div  class="card bg-gradient-lighter mt-3 shadow">
                        <div class="card-header-lg">
                        <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.cashier1.department">@{{ (queue.cashier1 || {}).department}}</h3>
                        <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-else>-</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body-sm">
                        <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold"  v-if="queue.cashier1"><strong>@{{ (queue.cashier1 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.cashier1 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer-sm">
                          <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 1</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div  class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter shadow mt-3">
                        <div class="card-header-lg">
                            <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-if="queue.cashier2.department">@{{ (queue.cashier2 || {}).department}}</h3>
                            <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-else>-</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body-sm">
                            <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold"  v-if="queue.cashier2"><strong>@{{ (queue.cashier2 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.cashier2 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer-sm">
                            <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter shadow mt-3">
                                <div class="card-header-lg">
                                    <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-if="queue.accounting1.department">@{{ (queue.accounting1 || {}).department}}</h3>
                                    <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-else>-</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body-sm">
                                    <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold"  v-if="queue.accounting1"><strong>@{{ (queue.accounting1 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.accounting1 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer-sm">
                                    <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 1</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter mt-3 shadow">
                        <div class="card-header-lg">
                        <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.accounting2.department">@{{ (queue.accounting2 || {}).department}}</h3>
                        <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-else>-</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body-sm">
                            <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold" v-if="queue.accounting2"><strong>@{{ (queue.accounting2 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.accounting2 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer-sm">
                          <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter shadow mt-3">
                            <div class="card-header-lg">
                                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.registrar1.department">@{{ (queue.registrar1 || {}).department}}</h3>
                                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-else>-</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body-sm">
                                <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold" v-if="queue.registrar1"><strong>@{{ (queue.registrar1 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.registrar1 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer-sm">
                                <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card bg-gradient-lighter mt-3">
                            <div class="card-header-lg">
                                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase" v-if="queue.registrar2.department">@{{ (queue.registrar2 || {}).department}}</h3>
                                <h3 class="text-default text-uppercase"  v-else>-</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body-sm">
                                <h1 class="display-1 font-weight-bold" v-if="queue.registrar2"><strong>@{{ (queue.registrar2 || {}).letter}}-@{{ (queue.registrar2 || {}).number}}</strong></h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer-sm">
                                <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>                     <p class="text-warning font-weight-bold">COUNTER 2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
```

you can do another thing to check your property is loaded at where loading condition is added.

```
<div  class="col-sm-6" v-if="queue.hasOwnProperty('id')">
```

I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry.Where will I put this code?
div  class="col-sm-6" v-if="queue.hasOwnProperty('id')">

Comment: replace the second line with this line of your HTML code.